# embed PDF not working in Android Chrome - plugin not supported

Tags: html, embed

I want to display  my PDF files on my web page.

This is my code which works perfectly my computers browser but id does not display in mobile's chrome shows the message

> plugin not supported

this is my code

```
<embed src="http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Drive PDF viewer with Object data

ex.

```
<object data="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" type="application/pdf">
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://health.ntuh.gov.tw/health/NTUH_e_Net/NTUH_e_Net_no91/%E7%99%8C%E7%97%87%E7%AF%A9%E6%AA%A2.pdf" type='application/pdf'>
</object>
```

Comment: This seems to work when I use a sample src hosted online "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"

However when I change it to  '<embed src="{{MyObject.file.url}}" ' i keep seeing a broken link. 

When look at the browser console I see the error "fused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'." So i changed the settings in  my django settings file to include "X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'" it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. PDF must be a download to browsing device So Some browsers can display with their pdf extension and **some may not have such a pdf extender**.
2. **Users can set their own PDF preferences** like display or not display after download or use a different PDF extender.
3. Embed is not the preferred method for serving a PDF, the most preferred method is text or a thumbnail cover / image icon with **`<a href=file.pdf download> click to download whole file</a>`** this reduces the load on the server (reduced cost like Amazon / book sites) [image]

4. **2nd best is one iFrame** on a page Below on Right (more than one means multiple downloads.)

[image]

5. Finally an Embed (Object is a method to be avoided as now depreciating / not good) See your Embed in an Object Above Left